# Define a generic lambda in C# and assign it to a variable to be used with MakeGenericMethod

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, reflection, system.reflection

I know I can define a generic function and then call it with Type parameters by help of reflection. Something like that:

```cs
private static void SomeFunc<Tf>()
{
    // Something type safe against Tf
}

public void CallingFunc()
{
    var someType = typeof(whatever); // This may be retrieved using reflection as well instead
    var someMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(SomeFunc)), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var typedMethod = someMethod.MakeGenericMethod(someType);
    typedMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Now, is there a way to declare this `SomeMethod<Tf>()` inline as a lambda, to avoid declaring it as a separate method in the class, but still being able to use it with `MakeGenericMethod`? Something like:

```cs
public void CallingFunc()
{
    var someType = typeof(whatever); // This may be retrieved using reflection as well instead

    // This obviously doesn't work as it requires Tf to be known at this stage, and we can have Tf only as a Type variable here => what should I do instead?
    var someMethod = new Action<Tf>(() => /* Something type safe against Tf */).Method;

    var typedMethod = someMethod.MakeGenericMethod(someType);
    typedMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Making `CallingFunc` generic as well is not an option - the `someType` variable is retrieved with reflection so is not known on compile time.

Comment: Why do you not want an extra method in your class? What actual problem does this cause?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348128/reflection-how-do-i-find-and-invoke-a-local-functon-in-c-sharp-7-0

Comment: @Sweeper, because the only reason for creating the said method is to wrap another (and writing just for that another method seems a bit silly to me, while constructing the call through reflection is way too complicated as it also involves lamdas inside), and also I want possibly leverage the lambda variables sharing from the outer function. Also, I wanted to avoid this chunk of code being strongly tied with the class itself to make it possible to reuse easily.

Comment: @Aage, that kinda helps, as I see the method of creating an Expression<Action<object>> instead and reflectively redefine it to (for example) Expression<Action<whatever>>, but that seems like a hack too tbh, which can break unexpectedly too. Apparently that's the only way though...

Answer (score -1):

Based on: https://gist.github.com/afreeland/6733381 with a little improvement:

```
public class ExpressionBuilder
    {
        // Define some of our default filtering options
        private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
        private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(List<GridHelper.Filter> filters)
        {
            // No filters passed in #KickIT
            if (filters.Count == 0)
                return null;

            // Create the parameter for the ObjectType (typically the 'x' in your expression (x => 'x')
            // The "parm" string is used strictly for debugging purposes
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "parm");

            // Store the result of a calculated Expression
            Expression exp = null;

            if (filters.Count == 1)
                exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]); // Create expression from a single instance
            else if (filters.Count == 2)
                exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]); // Create expression that utilizes AndAlso mentality
            else
            {
                // Loop through filters until we have created an expression for each
                while (filters.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Grab initial filters remaining in our List
                    var f1 = filters[0];
                    var f2 = filters[1];

                    // Check if we have already set our Expression
                    if (exp == null)
                        exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]); // First iteration through our filters
                    else
                        exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1])); // Add to our existing expression

                    filters.Remove(f1);
                    filters.Remove(f2);

                    // Odd number, handle this seperately
                    if (filters.Count == 1)
                    {
                        // Pass in our existing expression and our newly created expression from our last remaining filter
                        exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]));

                        // Remove filter to break out of while loop
                        filters.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
        }

        private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, GridHelper.Filter filter)
        {
            // The member you want to evaluate (x => x.FirstName)
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);

            var typeOfValue = filter.Value.GetType();
            // The value you want to evaluate
            ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value, typeOfValue);


            // Determine how we want to apply the expression
            switch (filter.Operator)
            {
                case GridHelper.Operator.Equals:
                    return Expression.Equal(member, constant);
                
                case GridHelper.Operator.NotEqual:
                    return Expression.Equal(member, constant);

                case GridHelper.Operator.Contains:
                    return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);

                case GridHelper.Operator.GreaterThan:
                    return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);

                case GridHelper.Operator.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

                case GridHelper.Operator.LessThan:
                    return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);

                case GridHelper.Operator.LessThanOrEqualTo:
                    return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

                case GridHelper.Operator.StartsWith:
                    return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant);

                case GridHelper.Operator.EndsWith:
                    return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);

            }

            return null;
        }

        private static BinaryExpression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, GridHelper.Filter filter1, GridHelper.Filter filter2)
        {
            Expression result1 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter1);
            Expression result2 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter2);
            return Expression.AndAlso(result1, result2);
        }


    }
    // Filter class
    public class GridHelper
    {
        public enum Operator
        {
            Contains,
            GreaterThan,
            GreaterThanOrEqual,
            LessThan,
            LessThanOrEqualTo,
            StartsWith,
            EndsWith,
            Equals,
            NotEqual,
            Or
        }

        public class Filter
        {
            public string PropertyName { get; set; }
            public object? Value { get; set; }
            public Operator Operator { get; set; }
        }
    }
```